# Charge 18650 with BCAP0050 2.7V 50F is possible?

Tags: power

my first question is!

I need to charge a 18650 with two BCAP0050 2.7V 50F

My question is... Is it possible?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: And how would you control the charging current?

Answer (score 3):

Nope...

[18650](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/2X-18650-9800mAh-Li-ion-3-7V-Rechargeable-Battery-For-Flashlight-Torch-Laser-RC-/182528555440) @ 9,800mAh, [converting](https://www.unitjuggler.com/convert-electriccharge-from-mAh-to-C.html?val=9800) is 35280 Coulombs.

[BCAP0050](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/maxwell-technologies-inc/BCAP0050-P270-T01/1182-1011-ND/3079275?utm_adgroup=Capacitors&mkwid=s6iCGp4zK&pcrid=87194132345&pkw=&pmt=b&pdv=c&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5u3dwLGK2gIVFLbACh2urgYNEAAYASAAEgLJffD_BwE) 2.7V 50F is only 135 Coulombs per cap. Assuming, that is, you can charge it to 2.7V without it exploding and extract every last charge from both of them that's only 270 Coulombs.

So you are a tad short or charge....

Comment: Hi, Just FYI there is no *genuine* 9800mAh 18650. The largest true capacity is around 3500mAh, although those have disadvantages (like decreased allowed discharge current) compared to lower capacity versions. Unfortunately seeing such fakes on Ebay as in that link, isn't a surprise :-(

Comment: @SamGibson ya but its so much difference I was not going to search any further ;)

Comment: Sure, understood, it's just a comment for future readers in case they read your answer (+1) and take the claimed battery capacity from that Ebay listing seriously :-)

Comment: sure? can you explain me how you calculate this? thx!

Comment: @fer344 click the links

Comment: but I use unitjungler and 1F is 26.80Ah https://www.unitjuggler.com/convert-electriccharge-from-Fd-to-Ah.html

how they calculate this? if BCAP0050 has 50F...

Comment: I answer Faraday ≠ Farad
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_constant